# Issue with permanent redirect implementation

Tags: apache, htaccess, mod-rewrite, 301-redirect

I have a tricky problem related to 301 redirections I badly need help with.
I tried to implement these via .htaccess, but ran into trouble.

The start of my .htaccess looks like this:

```
SetEnv PHP_VER 5
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

# Redirect non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

#--- GENERAL ---
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ index.php [L]
...
```

When I try to put a permanent redirect to index.php by adding R=301 in the square brackets,
I get a 404, and I have no idea where the error comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To force `www.` to be present in a domain name try this one instead (it's safer to have domain name hard coded):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=www.example.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [QSA,R=301,L]
```

A bit different version (with no domain name hard coded):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [QSA,R=301,L]
```

But if your configuration allows to to also accept requests for domain like `meow.example.com` .. then it will be redirected to `www.meow.example.com`.

Comment: The problem is with the index.php redirect when I try to make it permanent, not with the not-www to www.
I just put this one there in case it may have an impact.

Comment: @Argoron I see. It should not really matter .. but try adding `/` before `index.php`. Maybe you need to add `RewriteBase /` after `RewriteEngine on` line. Also ... what other rules do you have there (as they may be rewriting it further)? Can you post them all? Also ... are you able to reach it via `http://www.doamin.com/index.php` ?